# `xcrun: error: invalid active develop` when running make.jl to generate Julia docs

Tags: julia

I am trying to generate docs using `Documenter.jl` and when running `make.jl` I get the following error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I ran

`sudo xcode-select --install`

on the command line (MacOs Terminal) and followed the install instructions, the error stopped occurring and more of my files were able to be seen when running `make.jl`!